# error: expected primary-expression before X token

Tags: c++

Can you explain what the title error usually means?

I get it sometimes and I always eventually manage to fix it by accident, but I still don't have a clue what it means.

Here's an example from my current error:

```
Lca<RankVec, VertexVec> lca(graphList[0], dset, ss&);
```

> error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Comment: Is that supposed to be a function declaration or a function call?

Comment: Try deleting the '&'. What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` symbol is used as a bitwise AND operator. I.e. `0x3 & 0x5 == 0x1`. In this form, it's an infix operator between two expressions. From what you've told us, we now know that `ss` is an expression. Therefore, the compiler thinks `ss &` is the start of a bitwise AND expression, and it expects the right-hand side (which it calls "primary-expression"). However, instead of a right-hand side, the compiler encounters a `)`. That's obviously not the right-hand side of an AND expression.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell without any sample, but IIRC this happens as a consequence of using an undefined symbol (e.g. a function or a type without a declaration - not sure which exactly). In consequence, the parser gets confused and doesn't know what to expect further on in the code.

-(I believe this error only appears in conjunction with other errors? Or can you provide a code snippet which would give only this error on GCC compiler?)-

**edit:** In the code you provided, it is just the parser getting lost after encountering a "&" symbol in an illegal place - so a consequence of invalid syntax, not invalid semantics.

Such cryptic error messages (or often worse) are the consequence of the fact that C++'s grammar is undecidable and the compiler, upon seeing an error, cannot really guess what was supposed to be there and thus cannot generate a more accurate description.

Answer (score 2):

From Standard docs., *5.1 Primary expressions*,

> Primary expressions are **literals, names, and names qualified by the scope resolution operator ::**.

And also from *2.6 Tokens*,

> There are five kinds of tokens: **identifiers, keywords, literals,16) operators, and other separators**

Now, I believe the error is pretty descriptive..

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

Tough to suggest with the information in OP at the moment, but let me give it a try.

Assuming, that everying else is in place, for the expression in OP to be a function call, try changing the way you pass the last argument. If you want to pass it as a pointer, you have to use & before the name and not after.

```
Lca<RankVec, VertexVec> lca(graphList[0], dset, &ss);
```